# nokia here returns two locations for a single lat long

Tags: json, here-api, reverse-geocoding

When I make a nokia reverse geocoding call for a lat long, it returns me two results (location with address) for a single lat long.
For eg. when I used the following query URL:

```
URL url = new URL("http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=-53.31553,-68.64149999999998,1000&gen=1&mode=retrieveAddresses&app_id=oOnEEaBPJEG9JTqwTyjZ&app_code=WV2t5lCfD0NGpQMEjS2VBw");
```

I got the following result:

```
{
   "Response":{
      "MetaInfo":{
         "Timestamp":"2013-11-15T10:52:24.684+0000"
      },
      "View":[
         {
            "_type":"SearchResultsViewType",
            "ViewId":0,
            "Result":[
               {
                  "Relevance":1.0,
                  "Distance":615.1,
                  "MatchLevel":"street",
                  "MatchQuality":{
                     "Country":1.0,
                     "State":1.0,
                     "County":1.0,
                     "City":1.0,
                     "District":1.0,
                     "Street":[
                        1.0
                     ],
                     "PostalCode":1.0
                  },
                  "Location":{
                     "LocationId":"Link_811555088_R",
                     "LocationType":"point",
                     "DisplayPosition":{
                        "Latitude":-53.3246228,
                        "Longitude":-68.6432568
                     },
                     "MapView":{
                        "TopLeft":{
                           "Latitude":-53.32214,
                           "Longitude":-68.64146
                        },
                        "BottomRight":{
                           "Latitude":-53.32497,
                           "Longitude":-68.65595
                        }
                     },
                     "Address":{
                        "Label":"257-CH, 6300000 Porvenir, Magallanes y La Antártica Chilena, República de Chile",
                        "Country":"CHL",
                        "State":"Magallanes y La Antártica Chilena",
                        "County":"Tierra del Fuego",
                        "City":"Porvenir",
                        "Street":"257-CH",
                        "PostalCode":"6300000",
                        "AdditionalData":[
                           {
                              "value":"República de Chile",
                              "key":"CountryName"
                           },
                           {
                              "value":"Magallanes y La Antártica Chilena",
                              "key":"StateName"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     "MapReference":{
                        "ReferenceId":"811555088",
                        "SideOfStreet":"right",
                        "CountryId":"23488354",
                        "StateId":"23488754",
                        "CountyId":"23489032",
                        "CityId":"23488149"
                     }
                  }
               },
               {
                  "Relevance":1.0,
                  "Distance":627.0,
                  "MatchLevel":"street",
                  "MatchQuality":{
                     "Country":1.0,
                     "State":1.0,
                     "County":1.0,
                     "City":1.0,
                     "District":1.0,
                     "Street":[
                        1.0
                     ],
                     "PostalCode":1.0
                  },
                  "Location":{
                     "LocationId":"Link_925101778_L",
                     "LocationType":"point",
                     "DisplayPosition":{
                        "Latitude":-53.32497,
                        "Longitude":-68.64146
                     },
                     "MapView":{
                        "TopLeft":{
                           "Latitude":-53.32145,
                           "Longitude":-68.64146
                        },
                        "BottomRight":{
                           "Latitude":-53.32497,
                           "Longitude":-68.62151
                        }
                     },
                     "Address":{
                        "Label":"Ruta Complementaria I, 9420 Río Grande, Argentina",
                        "Country":"ARG",
                        "State":"Tierra del Fuego",
                        "County":"Río Grande",
                        "City":"Río Grande",
                        "Street":"Ruta Complementaria I",
                        "PostalCode":"9420",
                        "AdditionalData":[
                           {
                              "value":"Argentina",
                              "key":"CountryName"
                           },
                           {
                              "value":"Tierra del Fuego",
                              "key":"StateName"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     "MapReference":{
                        "ReferenceId":"925101778",
                        "SideOfStreet":"left",
                        "CountryId":"23294156",
                        "StateId":"23294735",
                        "CountyId":"3458765894026227595",
                        "CityId":"23294619"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Two locations are obtained. First giving the country as Chile and the next giving the country as Argentina. Which is the correct result ?

Comment: I doubt this is the correct place to ask this. We can't know what's going on in 3rd party api.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from the api response, the API itself does not know the answer. Look at this block:

```
"MatchQuality":{
   "Country":1.0
}
```

The same country match quality in both results. If you look at this address at google maps - you will see that it is very close to the border. Given that borders are not very precise on maps, it's easy to see why it does not know what country it is.

So, you have two options here:

1. Pick first one.
2. Decide by distance to nearest object. You have two objects found nearby, and the one with smaller distance is in Chile. So you can pick it then with high chance that it's right.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I could not get what you mean by the following:
"MatchQuality":{
   "Country":1.0
}

Also when I used here.com and searched using the same lat long, it gives me the country as Argentina which does not match with any of the two options that you have given.

Comment: MatchQuality is something the results are sorted by. AFAIR it is a number from 0 to 1 giving you a quality of match. So 1 means it is 100% sure. As about your example with here.com, here you go an example from google maps, which is sure it's Chile but not Argentina: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-53.31553,-68.64149999999998&sensor=true

Comment: I could find MatchQuality set as 1 for both the results in Nokia result. Then the data is selected based on nearest distance in the next step ? Also in the google result,I could find the result as Chile in all the results. Lets say if there are different results as in Nokia results, how the result is selected ?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. Looking at results I believe that here.com and google have different border information in their database. And Nokia probably has some fuzzy algorithm that has no precise border information at all. That's why it tries to tell you "I'm equally sure it's either Argentina or Chile".